# Can't export networkx to gexf - gephi

Tags: export, python-3.5, networkx, gephi

I have a big graph (1007 nodes; 1028 edges). I can export it to a jpeg; so far so good.

Now, I have an issue when exporting it to [gexf](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html) format to further open it with gephi.

I'd do ...

```
nx.write_gexf(G,'graph.gexf')
```

... and I get ...

```
  File "graph.py", line 524, in getTrace
    nx.write_gexf(G,'graph.gexf')
  File "<decorator-gen-444>", line 2, in write_gexf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/utils/decorators.py", line 227, in _open_file
    result = func_to_be_decorated(*new_args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 88, in write_gexf
    writer.add_graph(G)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 305, in add_graph
    self.add_nodes(G, graph_element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 340, in add_nodes
    node_data, default)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/networkx/readwrite/gexf.py", line 415, in add_attributes
    for val, start, end in v:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

As the link to [gexf](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.gexf.write_gexf.html) suggests, **I'm not mixing directed with unidrected graphs**. I've only created a Directed graph, added some nodes and edges, and that's it.

```
# We create the graph
G = nx.DiGraph()

# We add nodes and edges
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

# We establish attributes to nodes based no output parsing
nx.set_node_attributes(G,nodesAttrDic)
```

I do have the lastest networkx.

```
$ pip3 show networkx
Name: networkx
Version: 2.1
Summary: Python package for creating and manipulating graphs and networks
Home-page: http://networkx.github.io/
Author: NetworkX Developers
Author-email: networkx-discuss@googlegroups.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requires: decorator
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Lucas

Comment: Do you have a mixed graph, I mean with both directed and undirected links? This is because in that case networkx does not support exports to gexf.

Comment: No, I'm not mixing types of graphs. Only using a DiGraph ... I'll update the post ...